# Software to compress PDF

Tags: pdf, file-compression

I would like to compress a PDF file. The PDF size should be smaller than 1MB. Do you know a software that allow to compress PDF files to a given compressed size?

Comment: How big is the original?  Does it have a lot of images? Or could it be all images (not OCRed)?  In those cases it may not be possible to compress it further without making it unreadable.

Comment: Welcome birdman! It's not possible to create software to do exactly what you are asking. Every file has a limit to how much it can be compressed, depending on the contents of the file and the algorithm used.  Not every file (PDF or otherwise) can be compressed to be smaller than 1MB.

Comment: @StarGeek The original file size is 1025 KB and the file is a scan from a paper with no images

Comment: Are you sure that the entire page isn't just a image scan of that page?  Has it been OCRed?  Can you hightlight/copy text out of it?  It's common to scan a page and create a PDF out of the image that results from that scan.

Comment: @StarGeek It in fact a image scan of a page. I has not benn OCRed. I cannot hightlight/copy text out of it.